# load by attribute sku not working some times

Tags: product, model, sku

For Loading product by sku i'm using following function.
For some skus its working fine where as for some sku's not working.And these sku products existed in back end.

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
```

Can you help anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If neither of the following are working.

1. `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($sku, 'sku');`
2. `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);`

Then you could always use the resource model, `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product`, to get the product id via the function `getIdBySku` and then simply do a normal load.

Comment: Unfortunately no solution is working.

Answer (score 3):

***`loadByAttribute()`** basically load the ***product collection and  filter those collection by sku and then it return  that collection first item as a result***.

That ***particular sku does not exits*** at result ***because of***  `that particular product' does not exits to the products collection`

```
$collection = $this->getResourceCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect($additionalAttributes)
    ->addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $value)
    ->setPage(1,1);
```

As per as,magento ***a product does not visible at collection because of Product's***    [flat setting enable](http://inchoo.net/magento/flat-tables-in-magento-and-product-collection/) and  ***due to  some reason like  magento condition like  visibility, stock, website,store*** ,a product not include at product flat collection.

If  you load the product by load by  `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);` And this code is **direct called  of product  model** that  you can get ***result and also it does not called from collection,just call a particular model by id***  that

Answer (score 2):

Since `sku` attribute exists in `catalog_product_entity` table itself you can load product by the field like this:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($sku, 'sku');
```

Answer (score 1):

This only works when flat tables are turned off. The best solution is to use collection to fetch the product - it will always work.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                                            ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 'test-sku')
                                            ->getFirstItem();
```

Answer (score -1):

Disable the "use flat tables" config or reindex the product data